# probably gfs2 problem

Tags: centos, crash, gfs

We have a Mail Server (CentOS 6.5) with these component:

- Postfix
- Dovecot
- Mysql
- MailScanner (spamassassin,clamav)
- GFS2 Partition

Last night the server crashed and this is the kernel logs before that:

```
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: original: gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: pid: 24608
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: lock type: 2 req lock state : 1
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: new: gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: pid: 24608
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: lock type: 2 req lock state : 1
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel: G:  s:EX n:2/28b165f5 f:yfIqob t:EX d:EX/0 a:1 v:0 r:4 m:200
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
May 11 01:07:01 mail1 kernel:  H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:24608 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]
```

I found these solutions in this post titled: [/var/log/messages shows lines like "H: s:EX f:W e:0 p:19456 [imap] gfs2_fallocate+0xdc/0x540 [gfs2]" repeated many times and GFS2 file system becomes inaccessible in RHEL 6](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/712393) but we're not a Red Hat subscriber.

In the Dovecot logs I found the message:

> MySQL server has gone away

**NOTE:** Presently the MySQL data is stored on that GFS2 partition.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this problem?